# Export Application and API Settings from Auth0 via Web UI

Tags: auth0

I'm using Auth0 to manage authentication in a web app.
Since it took me a while to get it working, **I'd like to export the application and API settings** like for example:

- the application name
- the client id
- the supported auth methods
- the allowed callback URLs
- *basically everything else relevant to reproduce the application configuration*

I found a lot of documentation about exporting user data but nothing about exporting application or API settings.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the steps described here are just a **quick&dirty workaround** to read data from the Auth0 Management API without leaving your browser. I wonder why there is no "export" button for this directly in the UI. In both cases (application and API settings), open the network monitoring tab of your browser (usually F12); Then...

### Exporting Application Settings

Load the "settings" page of the application you'd like to export (e.g. `https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/eu/<your_auth0_tenant_name_here>/applications/<your_application_client_id_here>/settings`)

You'll see a GET request to `manage.auth0.com/api/clients/<your_application_client_id_here>`.
The response to this GET request is a JSON containing everything you need to reproduce the application settings; also sensitive data like the client secret and signing keys.

### Exporting API Settings

Load the "settings" page of the API you'd like to export (e.g. `https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/eu/<your_auth0_tenant_name_here>/apis/<your_api_id_here>/settings`)

You'll see a GET request to `manage.auth0.com/api/resource-servers/<your_api_id_here>`.
The response to this GET request is a JSON containing everything you need to reproduce the API settings.

Comment: having tried this recently, the settings call returns a document rather than json, so this no longer works (or I'm a n00b)